# Trace MS Access DB Changes

Tags: ms-access

I've got a legacy MS Access DB. How can I see the changes made to that DB? e.g. changes of Code etc. Does MS Access store it?

Comment: Good question but I think not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access is file based, perhaps there is a previous copy, otherwise, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [EQL Data Plugin](http://eqldata.com/) then you can track the current state of the database every time you upload it to the server.  Then you can get diffs, etc between versions.  (Disclosure: I work at EQL Data.)

Microsoft also makes a Visual SourceSafe plugin for Access that may be helpful to you, though it has a reputation for being buggy.

Comment: This works for code? That is, the stuff that's stored in that single BLOB field in a single record or one of the system tables?

Comment: Yes.  It uses a variation of Application.SaveAsText() to make the magic happen.

Comment: So it uses different methods for the diffs for the data and the code part?